# Conjugating Sylow 2-subgroups

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

$H$ is the subgroup of the alternating group $A_5$ generated by the permutations $(1\ 2)(3\ 4)$ and $(1\ 3)(2\ 4)$. I have proved that $H$ is a Sylow 2-subgroup of $A_5$, and found another Sylow 2-subgroup of $A_5$, namely $K = \{(), (2\ 3)(4\ 5), (2\ 4)(3\ 5), (2\ 5)(3\ 4)\}$. How should I go about finding a permutation, $a$, in $A_5$, such that $a^{-1}Ha = K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to map $(ab)(cd)$ to $(ef)(gh)$, conjugate by a permutation that sends $a\mapsto e$, $b \mapsto f$, $c \mapsto g$, and $d \mapsto h$.

So, to map $(12)(34)$ to $(23)(45)$, conjugate by $(12345)$. Note that conjugating $(13)(24)$ by the same element produces $(24)(35)$.

---

**Edit** The above assumes that conjugation by $a$ means $aHa^{-1}$. Since you are using the opposite convention $a^{-1}Ha$, you should conjugate by $(12345)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$H$ has $5$ as a common fixed point.
$H$ has $1$ as a common fixed point. Try some $a$ which takes $1$ to $5$
(or maybe $5$ to $1$).

Answer (score 1):

Your first Sylow-$2$ subgroup is in *that* $A_4$ which fixes $5$.

Second Sylow-$2$ subgroup is in *that* $A_4$ which fixes $1$.

Remember: in $A_4$, Sylow-$2$ subgroup is *unique*; thus, simply take any permutation which takes $1$ to $5$.